# Tor for OS X Icon doesn't open

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I've just downloaded Tor for my Mac and the icons won't open the browser. I've tried opening it off my desktop and out of my application. I click the icon and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you describe in your question which version of the Tor Browser Bundle you downloaded, and where you downloaded it from?  Do you mean "out of my application folder after copying it there" instead of "out of my application folder" and "I double-click the icon" rather than "I click the icon"?

Comment: Thanks for addressing my question. I downloaded Tor browser bundle from the Torproject site. I saved it to my applications folder. When I double click the Icon, I get the warning, "This file was downloaded from the internet" "Open, Cancel or show source."" I select "Open" and noting happened. So frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

On newer versions of Mac OS X you may have to manually allow it to open. From the Tor Project [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#mac):

1. Install: Drag the Tor Browser icon to the Applications folder and open the Applications folder.

[image: Screenshot showing the contents of the Tor Browser dmg file.]

2. Control-click: Control-click on the Tor Browser icon (click the mouse button while pressing the Control key on the keyboard) and choose “Open”.

[image: Screenshot of the Applications folder with the Tor Browser icon.]

3. Open: Click “Open” on the next screen.

[image: Dialog offering to open Tor Browser.]

If those steps don't work, drag the TorBrowser icon to the Trash then download a fresh copy and run through the steps again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you're using OS X 10.9 or newer, and are encountering an application auth cache issue.

When you run a new unsigned application, OS X will cache info about the application once you approve running it so that you don't have to keep approving it on each launch.

Sometimes, when you upgrade from a previous Tor Browser Bundle installation, this cache doesn't get cleared, so launches of the updated version fail.

This failure is perhaps more likely to occur if you piecemeal unzip or copy the new Tor Browser Bundle files into your older TorBrowserBundle_??-??.app container, rather than replacing the TorBrowserBundle_??-??.app container entirely with the new version.  [Substitute ??-?? for your language and country version; mine is en-US.]

As a workaround, you might try running the Tor Browser Bundle from a different folder than your previous location for the TorBrowserBundle_??-??.app container. This is very likely to create a fresh entry for the new version once you OK running the application.  For example, if the old TorBrowserBundle_??-??.app was in /Applications, place the new TorBrowserBundle_??-??.app version in ~/Desktop, ~/Applications, or the like.